# Why doesn't C++17 provide make_shared<T[]> whereas C++17 shared_ptr provides operator[]?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, c++17

Even though, one can get away fine with boost.

```
#include "boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.hpp"
auto int_arr_ptr = boost::make_shared<int[]>(100);
```

I'd like to know why the C++17 standard doesn't provide `std::make_shared<T[]>` whereas it provides `shared_ptr::operator[]`?

---

`std::shared_ptr::operator[]`
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at

`std::make_shared`
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

> - `std::shared_ptr` supports array types (as of C++17), but `std::make_shared` does not. This functionality is supported by `boost::make_shared`

`allocate_shared` and `make_shared` for arrays
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html

Comment: Yeah, that is odd, especially since there is such a `make_unique`.

Comment: Most likely this is just something that nobody suggested, so it didn't make it in

Comment: There is a proposal for this: [p0674](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0674r0.html).

Comment: @Barry So it's on its way then? Anyway, It's kind of odd that operator[] and make_share<t[]> seems to be on separated proposals even though they seems to be closely related.

Comment: @Justin I think it's been around so long. [N3870](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3870.html)

Comment: p0674 is in the working draft already.

Comment: @T.C. do you mean c++17 or c++2a ?

Comment: @sandthorn [p0674r0](http://wg21.link/p0674r0) is a 2017-06-15 paper. The draft for C++17 was voted out in March, i.e., it clearly didn't get into C++17 based on that paper. It seems [n3870](http://wg21.link/p3870) got discussed by LEWG in Issaquah 2014 and forwarded to LWG for inclusion into Fundamentals 2. I think there were changes suggested. I didn't find another discussion until it came back as [p0674](http://wg21.link/p0674r0) in Toronto where it got adopted. Seems nobody pushed for it to be discussed (e.g., by providing an update) before Toronto.

Comment: cppreference updated

Comment: A moment ago, someone voted this up, so I checked back here and clicked [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). I just found out there will be `make_shared_default_init` and `make_unique_default_init`, that's great! Of course, both support array type, yay! I'm a bit sorry for you, naked `new`.

Comment: @sandthorn: The "Why" part of your question cannot be answered conclusively. But I do not know how this question can be answered except by stating that this is going to be part of C++20.